# Can not find virtualization in my BIOS

Tags: virtual-machine, bios

This is how my BIOS looks like
[image]

ANd when I chooseSystem Configuration
[image]

More about my BIOS

```
BIOS Information
    Vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    Version: 68PZD Ver. F.0D
    Release Date: 04/07/2009
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 2048 kB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        PC Card (PCMCIA) is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        EDD is supported
        Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        Smart battery is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Function key-initiated network boot is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
    BIOS Revision: 15.13
    Firmware Revision: 95.29

Handle 0x000A, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
    Product Name: HP Compaq 6830s
```

I want to check if virtualization is enabled but where is the right place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To support virtualization, Intel processors must have the VT-x feature.

You may not have the VT-x feature in your processor; in which case, your BIOS won't have the option.

The Core 2 Duo processor in your laptop doesn't always have VT-x - it depends on the model.  Run the following:

```
$ grep "vmx" /proc/cpuinfo
```

If you get an output similar to the following:

```
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
```

`grep` has found the letter `vmx` in the output, which signifies that your processor supports VT-x.  If you don't get an output (which I suspect will be the case) then your processor doesn't support VT-x.  Hence no BIOS option.